# How to define some macros as 'private' to a module, when using `macro_use` in Rust?

Tags: macros, namespaces, rust

I have a file which contains shared macros for a Rust project.

Since I want to re-use the macros across the crate (between modules), I declare the module with `#[macro_use]`.

While writing the macros, I split out some shared logic into a macro to avoid repetition, in this case I can't use a private function, it needs to be a macro.
If possible, I'd like to hide this shared macro so it can't be used directly by other modules.

Is there a way to make some macros *private*, so they aren't exposed to other modules in the same crate via `#[macro_use]`?

Answer (score 9):

There actually is an idiom in Rust, to hide away "implementation-detail" macros.

Rather than declaring a separate macros, you can instead declare a separate *case* within the existing macro. The examples I've seen would use the `impl` keyword for this, and the `impl` cases are located at the bottom of the macro definition.

Thus, instead of:

```
macro_rules! hello_impl {
    ($name:expr) => {
        println!("Hello {}!", $name);
    }
}

macro_rules! hello_world {
    () => {
        hello_impl!("world");
    }
}
```

You use:

```
macro_rules! hello_world {
    () => {
        hello_world!(impl "world");
    },
    (impl $name:expr) => {
        println!("Hello {}!", $name);
    }
}
```

This way, there is no implementation macro any longer; and you only have one macro to export.

Comment: The example shows a single implementation and use. How could this be shared between multiple macros?

Comment: @ideasman42: Nothing precludes you from invoking `hello_world!(impl ...)` from another macro. It is not so much denied as hidden.

Comment: This is the [Internal Rules pattern](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/internal-rules.html), right? (except for using `impl` instead of `@rulename`)

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a name for it, but it seems to match, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the macro namespace bounds can only be constrained across crates.

The only way to make some macros private is to split the module into a crate, then use `#[macro_export]` to define which macros are exported from that crate.

See [Rust's documentation on this topic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#scoping-and-macro-importexport).

---

Note: there may be some obscure way to do this, but from reading documentation it seems this feature isn't officially supported, which is why I posted this answer - happy to be proven wrong!

The #rust IRC channel states that this is something which might be supported in Macros 2.0.